# Java - drawing Polynomials

Tags: java, swing, unicode, superscript

I'm just wondering how can I draw a polynomial like that X^2+2*X^4+... 
in efficient way and make it look like a real one. I mean powers is up-script and so.

Comment: *powers is up-script* - is this a hidden hint, that the input to your algorithm is a polynom in some sort of formatted text or html?

Comment: How do you store your polynomials?

Comment: From the accepted answer I suppose you want to *format the formula*, but from the question I would have thought you want to draw a graph of the function. Please try to make clearer questions in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an environment with a good Unicode font, you could relatively easily create your own polynomial `toString()`. Unicode has all [Arabic numerals defined as superscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), most of them in the [Superscripts and Subscripts block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/superscripts_and_subscripts/list.htm):

```
x⁰: U+2070 
x¹: U+00B9  // Not in U207x range!
x²: U+00B2  // Not in U207x range!
x³: U+00B3  // Not in U207x range!
x⁴: U+2074
x⁵: U+2075
x⁶: U+2076
x⁷: U+2077
x⁸: U+2078
x⁹: U+2079
x⁻: U+207B
```

Thus, constructing x⁻⁴² (x^-42) would be possible by printing `U+0078 U+207B U+2074 U+00B2`.

Notice that the font you use to print this must have these characters defined.

Comment: i searched for them .. but i found the 00B2 and 00B3 .. i thought that this is the only ones there :D

Comment: mmmm ... can u recommend a font ?? cuz all the 207x isn't working :(

Answer (score 2):

The Unicode approach has considerable appeal, but it requires font support. As an alternative, consider [*How to Use HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html), e.g.

```
new JLabel("<html><i>x</i><sup>2</sup> + <i>x</i><sup>4</sup></html>")
```

[image: Polynomial.png]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to help you get started, here's what you need to do on a high level:

- Extend a JPanel. This new class (lets say PolynominalPanel extends JPanel) will draw your polynominal.
- Override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method
- Use the "Graphics" argument to set the linestroke of your choice (cast to Graphics2D and use setStroke()).
- Define a new class that transforms X and Y values to values in your JPanel coordinates. This allows you to translate, mirror, rotate ... etc.. all your points in a uniform way. (So for each X and Y in your polynominal, transform this with a formula of your choosing, so that the polynominal is drawn in the bounds of the JPanel).The point here is that you want to map a part of your polynominal to the bounds of your PolynominalPanel. This is the part of the polynominal you are interested in. This depends on the polynominal.
- Sample your polynominal in a discrete way. For instance, you could sample it for each X pixel, or possibly you could sample it at a lower rate for better performance. (Though per pixel should be fine)
- Use the Graphics.drawLine() method to draw lines. You should use the transformed values that you have sampled before.

And voila, you're done!

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want an API, perhaps you can reuse some of the JMathTools functionality. It doesn't allow you to plot polynominals, but it does offer panels that have move, pan and rotate controls. It also allows you to add lines to your plot. So basically you would still have to break your polynomials up into lines, but it would be less work than I described above. I've used it before to draw lines and it works well if you simply want a quick visualization.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean: drawing the formula or drawing the graph. It seems you want the former. You could have a look at LaTex.

Comment: Ah, true, you added java and swing tags. You didn't mention them in the question though. I'm not aware of a way to display LaTex in a Swing component, I'm afraid.

Comment: Use `dvipng` and display the resulting PNG file in your Swing component.